# Why is the default Spring Security strategy AffirmativeBased?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

From the [spring security docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-access-manager) for AccessDecisionManager:

> The default strategy is to use an AffirmativeBased AccessDecisionManager with a RoleVoter and an AuthenticatedVoter.

The [AffirmativeBased](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/AffirmativeBased.html) voter:

> grants access if *any* AccessDecisionVoter returns an affirmative response

According to the docs, the RoleVoter will vote based on whether the authenticated object has the correct ROLE_ authority, and the AuthenticatedVoter based on whether or not the object is authenticated.

My confusion is, what is the AuthenticatedVoter object voting on? In my application I only want someone with ROLE_USER to access a resource. But I'm also setting setAuthenticated(true) on my implementation of the AbstractAuthenticationToken.

From reading of the docs the AffirmativeBased strategy would only need authenticated to be true to access the resource and wouldn't bother with the ROLE requirement. Is there a different "is authenticated" value that's actually being checked?

I know about the UnanimousBased strategy, but it seems like I haven't understood the authenticated test or else there would be a big security hole in the default implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you configure authorization, you provide configuration attributes, for example `hasRole('admin')`. During voting, the voters will check if it supports, otherwise it will abstain from voting. In case of `AuthenticatedVoter`, it will abstain from voting if the access is configured for `Role`. See source code of [vote method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/vote/AuthenticatedVoter.java#L100).

Comment: Ah ok, so the isAuthenticated value for the authentication token is separate from the attributes, such as "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY". And it will abstain unless you've actively set a rule that a resource must have that attribute.

Good answer pointing to the code, thank you.

Comment: We have a similar problem. When we come to the voting, we have both a role attribute ROLE_ADMIN and IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY. AuthenticatedVoter will NOT abstain and the use can access the resource. Even if the role is wrong.

Comment: There are other AccessDecisionManagers. For example, org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased. Check others, and choose whatever suits your case or go for custom implementation.